# Script to toggle the names of two XML files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a script so that I can toggle between two XML files say A.xml and B.xml .On running the script the name of the XML files should change means A becomes B and B becomes A. Please suggest how to do this on windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Rename both files.

Obvious solution:

```
ren a.xml temp.xml
ren b.xml a.xml
ren temp.xml b.xml
```

Of course, that doesn't save you from races with other processes but I guess if you need to worry about that you wouldn't be asking this question in the way you have ...

Comment: this simple approach has a problem of colliding with the temp name. To avoid it, you need to create a unique filename, which is tricky in bat files. Use %RANDOM% in the temporary file name, check if already exists and if it does keep trying new %RANDOM%. IF EXIST %RANDOM%.TMP GOTO AGAIN.

Comment: PA: Of course, but that also has races. You have no transactional integrity in batch files so anything you try is only an approximation. The question is also vague enough in what they want, so this can work without problems if they don't do it multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: yes, I agree, in fact instead of *avoid* I should have written *alleviate* or minimize